# Is this a deathstalker

Tags: species-identification, zoology, animal-husbandry

[image]
I want to know is this a death stalker ?

Comment: What are its dimensions? How long is the body, and how long to the tip of the tail? Where and in what sort of environment did you find it? Please [edit] your question and add as many details as possible to assist in identification. On the surface it *looks* like a deathstalker scorpion, but we can't tell for sure without more information.

Comment: Where did you see this? Looks interesting.